# How can I check if a variable contains another variable within a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Assuming the following batch file

```
set variable1=this is variable1
set variable2=is
set variable3=test

if variable1 contains variable2 (
    echo YES
) else (
    echo NO
)

if variable1 contains variable3 (
    echo YES
) else (
    echo NO
)
```

I want the output to be a YES followed by a NO

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've resolved this with the following

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set variable1=this is variable1
set variable2=is
set variable3=test

if not "x!variable1:%variable2%=!"=="x%variable1%" (
    echo YES
) else (
    echo NO
)

if not "x!variable1:%variable3%=!"=="x%variable1%" (
    echo YES
) else (
    echo NO
)

endlocal
```

I got the basic idea from the following answer but it wasn't searching by a variable so it wasn't completely what I was looking for.

[Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006016/384853)

Answer (score 6):

another way:

```
echo/%variable1%|find "%variable2%" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (echo yes) else (echo no)
```

the `/` prevents output of `Echo is ON` or `Echo is OFF` in case `%variable1%` is empty.

Comment: This fails for variable1=`/?`, variable1=`on`, and variable1=`off`. Consider `echo foobar %variable1%|find "%variable2%" >nul`, which does fail for variable2=foobar.

Answer (score 4):

Gary Brunton's answer did not work for me.

If you try with `set variable1="C:\Users\My Name\"`, you will end up with an error :

```
 'Name\""' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Adapting this answer [Find out whether an environment variable contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491383/find-out-whether-an-environment-variable-contains-a-substring), I ended up with :

```
echo.%variable1%|findstr /C:"%variable2%" >nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 (
   echo Found
) else (
   echo Not found
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on [JBEs answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181067/854680).  It distinguishes empty/undefined variables.

```
if not defined VARIABLE1 (echo VARIABLE1 undefined) & goto proceed
if not defined VARIABLE2 (echo VARIABLE2 undefined) & goto proceed
echo %VARIABLE1% | find "%VARIABLE2%" > nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo Not found) & goto proceed
echo Found
:proceed
```

If the value of `VARIABLE1` contains parentheses, e.g. the value `C:\Program Files (x86)`, then the parentheses may be interpreted as a distinct command rather than echoed, causing an error.  Substrings like `(x86)` can be escaped with carets for purposes of echoing properly, e.g.:

```
SET V1_DISPLAY=%VARIABLE1%
if /i "%V1_DISPLAY:(x86)=%" NEQ "%V1_DISPLAY%" set V1_DISPLAY=%V1_DISPLAY:(x86)=^^(x86^^)%
echo %V1_DISPLAY% | find "%VARIABLE2%" > nul
```

The second statement, above, can be read as follows:

*If replacing substring `(x86)` with nothing makes a difference, then `(x86)` is present, so replace any occurrence of `(x86)` with `^^(x86^^)`, where each pair of carets represent an escaped single caret.*