# Windows check string contains another not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this batch file to append a environment variable if not exists

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set echo off                        

set envPath=%PATH%
set comPath=";D:\Package\Libraries\Lib"

if x%envPath:comPath=%==x%envPath% (
    setx PATH "%PATH%;D:\Package\Libraries\Lib" /M
)
pause
```

But its not working and says file was unexpected this time

I wrote based on [Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file)

Comment: You need `if "!envPath:%comPath%=!"=="!envPath!"` ... your form tests if the literal string `comPath` is present; you want to see if the _contents_ of `comPath` is present.  For this you need to use both `%` and `!` references.

Comment: @Billa, you took an example code which should not be used. See anwers on [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915767) and [Setting path environment variable in batch file only once on Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885906) and [How can I use a .bat file to remove specific tokens from the PATH environment variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38664286/3074564) for better solutions and an explanation why not using local __PATH__ on updating system __PATH__.

Comment: Detecting whether a value exists within PATH is much more complicated than you realize. Have a look at [How to check if directory exists in %PATH%?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8046515/1012053)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Very useful for every reader of this thread to outline details of the complex and far not obvious issue of updating global PATH var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment, use delayed expansion in the *main string*, and regular expansion in the *replace string*. Run this batch as Admin from shortcut or from Admin Cmd Prompt:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "comPath=D:\Package\Libraries\Lib"                     
set "envPath=%PATH%" & set "Separator="
if not "%envPath:~-1%" == ";" set "Separator=;"

if "!envPath:%comPath%=!"=="%envPath%" (
    setx PATH "%PATH%%Separator%%comPath%" /M )
timeout 5
exit /b
```

Note that updated PATH will be re-read from Registry only upon Cmd restart. If you need to use the amended PATH in the same batch, use SET instead of SETX to set the PATH temporarily for that Cmd session.

In a similar construct, if your extra path `comPath` is set *inside* IF or FOR loop, use `call set "PATH=%%envPath:!comPath!=%%"` instead.

Comment: why `timeout 5` and `exit` needed?

Comment: If this is your entire script, _exit /b_ will cleanup Cmd memory, so you can start a new batch from the same open Cmd window. And _timeout_ is usually added for debugging, when you start a batch by doubleclick, and need some time to read its echo or error output before its window closes. It just gives you the construct to test code variations. :)

Comment: Tried this but got error again. Also I modified `set "comPath=;D:\Package\Libraries\Lib"` to `set comPath=";D:\Package\Libraries\Lib"`

Comment: Try this without modifying anything **at all**. If error, post the exact error printout.

Comment: I ran as it is. It didn't add the new value. It  just ran the timer `Waiting for 5-0 seconds` and did nothing

Comment: @Billa You clearly missed the bit that said "Note that updated PATH will be re-read from Registry only upon Cmd restart."

Comment: @Billa I tested it in Win10 64-bit, and it works _perfect_. To update the PATH, you must run the batch as Admin. What Windows version do you use? Also, after you run the script, close Cmd window, start Cmd again, and type echo %PATH%. It should list your path among others, but they are sorted in alphabet order, not necessarily at the end.

Comment: Is there any reason why variable declaration used like `set "comPath=;D:\Package\Libraries\Lib"`? instead of `set comPath=";D:\Package\Libraries\Lib"`

Comment: Print your PATH var. Do you see any path shown with parentheses? Replace function wouldn't work, as it can't find such. :)

Comment: If I restart the machine and run the script, its adding again.. so getting duplicate entries... :(

Comment: @Billa I updated the answer, after reading the newly added comments links to your question by _Mofi_ and _dbenham_. Tested again, and works pretty well.

Comment: Got it. But when I ran the previous version with same SETX /M it appending every time when i restart and run

Comment: It was due to extra `;`